# Meteor app not finding 'xhr-sync-worker.js'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, deck.gl

I am trying to run a deck.gl example inside a meteor app. But I am facing this error.

```
modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:231 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './xhr-sync-worker.js'
    at makeMissingError (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:231)
    at Function.require.resolve (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:263)
    at xmlhttprequest.js (xml.js:30)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:238)
    at Window.js (xml.js:30)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:343)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:238)
    at api.js (xml.js:30)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d18…:343)
```

However the said js module is present in the meteor app `node_modules` folder.

```
/caseview/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-sync-worker.js
```

How can I make my app see it?. Note That I am not importing it directly in my code, as can be seen from the stack trace above. Perhaps this is a meteor bug.

Comment: What does the relevant code in your app look like? Are you attempting to import `xhr-sync-worker` directly in your code?

Comment: No I am not importing it directly. It's being imported from some other package in the meteor stack

Comment: More info is required, please edit your post with: Code snippet where this lib is used.

Comment: I repeat, the Lib is not used in my code. The stack trace shows where it been called from. Those are all libraries from meteor framework or bundled by it during the build process.

Comment: Have you ever found a fix for this problem? I find that this always happens when running meteor test.

Answer (score 3):

Late reply but I was facing the same problem in a meteor / react app, trying to import JSDOM in a component. After some long hours there's a way.
Step 1 : JSOM library use relative path for require :

```
node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:31
const syncWorkerFile = require.resolve ? require.resolve("./xhr-sync-worker.js") : null;
```

Meteor build all your code so the relative path is no longer ok.
Solution : replacing this line with an absolute path :

```
const syncWorkerFile = "${require.resolve('jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-sync-worker.js')}";
```

Now your app is working but if you do a meteor npm install you will have to redo this modification.

Step 2 : create and use your own package
in node_modules/jsdom do a yarn pack to generate a tar.gz with your modification (jsdom use yarn so you can't use npm)

move your archive : cp ./jsdom-v18.1.1.tgz ../../dependencies/

and replace jsdom with yours freshly build: meteor npm install dependencies/jsdom-v18.1.1.tgz

Comment: Just changing the relative path to the absolute path worked a treat ... did not have to do anything else thanks @pipou

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem and was able to resolve my issue, so I thought I'd include it here for posterity.

I had added JSDOM through NPM, and inadvertently required jsdom on both my client side and server side code.

By wrapping the require in a Meteor.isServer condition I resolved my problem.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  const jsdom = require("jsdom");
}
```

So if you are running into this issue double check you are not trying to run the code on the client unintentionally.

Comment: Worked for me, the only caveat was that I've been using `import` syntax for everything, so for this to work correctly created `jsdom-setup.js` with this and then done `import './jsdom-setup.js'` at the top of my `tests/main.js`

Answer (score 0):

I had these issues in past in Meteor where it says some file is not found in `node_modules`. I don't know the exact reason why this occurs but yes it looks like some Meteor bug.

So, how I fixed this was by deleting `node_modules` folder and then doing `meteor npm install` again. Try this and I think this work in your case too. Let me know if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and it seemed to disappear when I renamed the file I was requiring JSDOM in from **index.js** to **index.es6**. I believe it have to do with the ***...require();*** function.